# How to modify webpack.render.config.js in a vue-cli project?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I want to do this
in webpack.render.config.js:

```
let whiteListedModules = ['vue'];
```

change to

```
let whiteListedModules = ['vue', 'element-ui'];
```

but I used vue-cli to create my project, So how can I achieve this?

Comment: did you find an answer to that question ? I'm facing a similar issue